# Formatting output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to write a powershell script and running into a problem that google can't seem to tell me how to fix. Basically, i have 4 variables:

```
$myDuration = $myObj.Duration
$mySubject = $myObj.Subject
$myStart = $myObj.Start
$myLocation = $myObj.Location
```

I'm trying to send an email where the body is:

```
"Your meeting ({0}) will begin {1}. It will be held at {2} and last approximately {3}."   -f $mySubject,$myStart,$myLocation,$myDuration
```

Now, if I ONLY include one variable, it works just fine. For example, "Your meeting {0}" -f $myLocation  correctly outputs the value stored in $myLocation.

WHen I include more then one, my output for each variable is the exact string "System.Object[]". (IE "Your meeting (System.Object[]) will begin System.Object[]. It will be held at System.Object[] and last approximately System.Object[].") Any ideas why it bugs when I include more then one variable? From everything I've read about on Google there shouldn't be an issue.

Thank you for your time.  Editing for hopefully better clarification of my issue.

Comment: How are you including multiple values? You haven't shown the actual code that's broken.

Comment: I thought that's exactly what I was doing:      "Your meeting ({0}) will begin {1}. It will be held at {2} and last approximately {3}."   -f $mySubject,$myStart,$myLocation,$myDuration.   If I have "Your meeting {0}" -f $myDuration, for example it outputs 30. But when I have more then one argument they ALL output System.Object[] instead

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that it was scrolling.

Comment: I edited it. Hopefully my problem is more clear now. Thank you very much alroc for pointing it out to me.

Comment: What are the values of all those `$myFoo` variables?

Comment: Can't format right for some reason. Duration is Int32. Location is String, Start is DateTime and Subject is a String.

Comment: Josh, I think you are looking in the wrong place. The formatting is fine. Your problem is upstream. That is, your variables don't contain what you think they contain. Try stepping through the script in the ISE, and examine the contents of your variables to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Dangph. You are correct, but I'm not quite sure how to explain why. The code I wrote is capturing Outlook appointment data, and it's capturing both of my two test appointments at once. As I mention earlier, I casted everything to strings and that works. It's also what showed me this new problem. So you're correct, I need to figure out how to seperate each instance into its own variable. Here goes new fun!!!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that one or more of the fields in `$myObj` is something other than a string and can't be converted to a string easily, and that's throwing the formatter off. Have a look at this code:

```
$myDuration = "Duration";
$mySubject = "Subject";
$myStart = "Starttime";
$myLocation = "Location";

"Your meeting ({0}) will begin {1}. It will be held at {2} and last approximately {3}."   -f $mySubject,$myStart,$myLocation,$myDuration

$myObj = @{"Duration"=[int32]123456;"Subject"="Subject2";"Starttime"=(get-date);"Location"="Location2"};
$myDuration = $myObj.Duration;
$mySubject = $myObj.Subject;
$myStart = $myObj.Starttime;
$myLocation = $myObj.Location;
"Your meeting ({0}) will begin {1}. It will be held at {2} and last approximately {3}."   -f $mySubject,$myStart,$myLocation,$myDuration
```

And my output is:

```
Your meeting (Subject) will begin Starttime. It will be held at Location and last approximately Duration.
Your meeting (Subject2) will begin 2/13/2014 10:30:39 PM. It will be held at Location2 and last approximately 123456.
```

It all works as expected.

Comment: Two questions. First, I've tried appending .ToString() to the end of each of my variable declarations, ie ($myDuration = $myObj.Duration.ToString()) and that didn't help. Second, if the problem WERE that it had a hard time handling strings, how come each variable outputs correctly when it's by itself? For example, MyStart is a DateTime and yet without being casted somehow, it outputs correctly by itself. I hope this question made sense.

Comment: Also, thank you very much for your reply. I'm not trying to be difficult but you use Subject2, etc and I don't understand why. You didn't create them, instantiate them, or use them except in your array. I could copy this verbatim and try it but it doesn't explain to me the how/why.

Comment: I'm demonstrating that if you use pure strings, the code *does* work. Which distills the problem to the data types in `$myObj`.

Comment: Thank you alroc, you are correct. After your suggestion, I googled how to cast them as strings, and that fixed the problem. It opened a new problem but it's irrelevant to this thread. :P Thank you very much.

Comment: I've updated my example using the data types you say your code is using. It still works properly for me. I concur with @dangph, your issue is further upstream.

Comment: Thank you both, Alroc and Dangph. I -may- have found the problem, and if I'm wrong about this please feel free to explain why. The snippet I was using to get Outlook Calendar appointments was grabbing multiple appointments. On MY end, I was storing this data to one variable. So my one variable was storing multiple appointments. I added a parameter to only include appointments whose body contains a specific string. After this, it was only including the one specific appointment. THEN, I removed where I casted my values to string and tested the output. Now, it works correctly. Sound right? Thanks

Comment: It's a little hard to follow but generally, yes, if you try to cram a collection in where a single object is expected, you'll just get `Object[]`.